# MarkLogic-specific way (or faster way) to do a positional query?

Tags: marklogic

I have the following query that works, but is very slow since I guess it has to look in each and every document instead of making use of the indexes:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace appl="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/appl";
declare namespace appls="http://ap.org/schemas/09/2011/applsearch";

let $p := cts:and-query((
      cts:element-range-    query(xs:QName("appls:ArrivalDateTime"),">=",fn:dateTime(xs:date("2003-01-01"), xs:time("00:00:00"))),
      cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("appls:ArrivalDateTime"),"<=",fn:dateTime(xs:date("2003-01-31"), xs:time("23:59:59"))),
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("appl:MediaType"), "text")
      ))

let $results := cts:search(fn:doc(), $p, "unfiltered")
return
 for $result in $results

where cts:contains($result//appl:block/appl:p[position()=last()], "information from:")
return fn:document-uri($result)
```

I tried using a cts:element-word-query with the punctuation-sensitive option switched on, but I believe we didn’t index that in our database due to space restrictions so it wouldn’t work.

Would love any suggestions on how I might speed this up or improve it. If adding indexing is my only recourse, I guess I can go back to our admins and see what’s possible, but hoping I won’t have to go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that `unfiltered` helps much in this query: most of the time will probably be spent in the `cts:contains` expression. Generally speaking, the built-in filtering is very fast.

Anyway the first thing I would try would be to add a `cts:element-word-query(xs:QName('appl:p'), "information from")` to the `and-query` at `$p`. But keep the `cts:contains` expression too. This way the index lookup gets to check for 'information from' in any `appl:p` element, which should eliminate some documents. Then the `cts:contains` should have less work to do. You can help it out a bit by replacing the '//appl:block' step with a full path, if the content structure allows. If there will only be one last-p, you might also write the expression so that it can stop after it finds the first one.

Comment: You were right about "unfiltered", turns out this was preventing the query from really working well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there really is an index that contains the position of individual elements. Best solution I'm afraid would be to copy the `appl:p[position()=last()]` element and give it a unique name, so you could use `cts:element-value-query` directly onto it.

If the where clause filters out lots of **false positives**, and if those cases don't contain a `appl:p` with the value 'information from:' at all, then using a `cts:element-word-query` could help a lot.

You don't necessarily need an index to use `element-word-queries`.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks and you're right about the indexing, what I meant and probably didn't articulate much was there seems to be a specific setting in MarkLogic admin that allows you to turn on or off indexing for punctuation and due to space limitations at the moment, we have it off. If i could search on that exact phrase "information from:" (including the colon), I'd have much better results. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @zrdunlap There is no specific punctuation setting for indexing. It does make a difference. If you search for 'exact' matches, word indexes provide rough results, and they need to be checked/filtered to eliminate false positives. But that is done automatically, it 'only' takes a bit of performance..

Comment: Perhaps we're on the wrong track then, when you say search for 'exact' matches, how do you mean? I was trying to do this using cts:contains since in a controlled test, I can confirm that using cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("appl:p"), "information from:") returns results with "information from" without the colon.

Comment: @zrdunlap You can pass in query options as a third param to cts:element-qord-query. Adding a third param 'exact' should be sufficient..

Comment: Thanks, for your help, I'll report back on any success

Comment: Actually, that seems to require "unstemmed" word searches to be on which I believe requires additional indexing.

Comment: @zrdunlap 'exact' is a short-hand for a combination of sensitivity flags. You could also only supply punctuation-sensitive, or a specific subset that is allowed with your current indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also flag the last one at ingest time (e.g. make it `<appl:p last="true">...</appl:p>`) so that you can leverage the indexes to avoid the where clause.

Comment: Thanks, yeah we'll have to see about doing this for the future.